# Converting 4D Vector to Long

Tags: java, vector, hash, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to figure out a way of converting a 4D vector into a bounded long. However, the vector and the resultant long have certain restrictions. The vector itself is composed of 4 integers: The first integer can be anything within Java's capability (so Integer.MIN_VALUE all the way to Integer.MAX_VALUE). The second and fourth integers are always between -2999984 and 2999984 (both inclusive). And finally, the third is always between 0 and 255 (again, both inclusive). So it follows this format:

```
([Integer min - Integer max], [-2999984 - 2999984], [0 - 255], [-2999984 - 2999984])
```

That vector needs to be converted to a long between -824629322721380016 and 824629339968358064.

I'm aware that there is probably no function that results in a 1 to 1 matching, but I'm trying to figure out a function that will result in as few collisions as possible.

If you are wondering, these bounds for the vector and long are not arbitrary. As I've tagged the post with Minecraft, I ought to explain why. I'm trying to match a certain blockpos in one dimension with a blockpos in another. The 4D vector is [dimension id, x pos, y pos, z pos] and the resultant long is the serialized form of BlockPos (BlockPos#fromLong). You can see [this](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/53230-mod-loading-ordercreating-blocks-at-runtime/?do=findComment&comment=257949) forums post that sparked my inquiry. I'm asking here because my queston is necessarily MC specific, as it's mainly mathematical and code-based.

Comment: Does this function need to be easily reversible? Or can it be one way?

Comment: No, the function does not need to be reversible. Just as long as the vector gets converted into a long with the above restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your 4d vector into bits, making that bit representation into a BigInteger and hashing that integer using a hashing algorithm designed for low collisions.

Your number of 'buckets' is effectively the range of the long.

According to this Murmur2 appears to be the best hashing for numbers.:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

You can Google for Murmur2 java implementations, but here is one such example at the time of the writing of this answer:
https://github.com/sangupta/murmur

Worth noting that if you could limit your number of dimensions to 65536 (16 bits) - you could have a 1 to 1 hash on bits alone.  Possibly could do this by limiting the number of virtual worlds that a user can go into?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be done. A long only holds 64 bits, but your 4D-Vector needs 32 + 23 + 8 + 23 > 64.

If you could restrict your input a little bit to make it fit, you could convert it similar to the following code (example of a 2D-int-Vector <-> long conversion):

```
long toLong(int int1, int int2) {
    return ((long) int1 << 32) | (int2 & (-1L >>> 32));
}

int[] toInts(long l) {
    int[] ints = new int[2];
    int[0] = (int) (both >> 32);
    int[1] = (int) both;
    return ints;
}
```